# How to properly render images using a map function with Gatsby.js

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, gatsby, gatsby-image

This app was originally built using react, however we have decided to convert everything over and use Gatsbyjs. I am new to Gatsby and I am trying to get my images to render correctly using the artist data.
Here is how this part of the data was originally built:

```
const images = [
  AngelAndJaamiHeadshot,
  BillyHawkinsHeadshot,
  BostonWellsHeadshot,
  BreanahAlvizHeadshot,
  CarloCollantesHeadshot,
  CarloDarangHeadshot,
  ChrisLumbaHeadshot,
  ChrisMartinHeadshot,
  CJDelaVegaHeadshot,
  CyeBongalosHeadshot,
  DanielKimHeadshot,
  DavidDarkieSimmonsHeadshot,
  // DavidDiosoHeadshot,
  DavidSlaneyHeadshot,
  DavinLawsonHeadshot,
  DevinHeadshot,
  DustinYuHeadshot,
  EmilyRowanHeadshot,
  HonrieDualanHeadhot,
  HughAparenteHeadshot,
  JaamiWaaliVillalobosHeadshot,
  JeremyBorjaHeadshot,
  JonathanSisonHeadshot,
  JordanBautistaHeadshot,
  JordanRileyHeadshot,
  JuliaKestnerHeadshot,
  JustinArcegaHeadshot,
  KaitlynSungHeadshot,
  KaylarPrieteHeadshot,
  KeyanaReedHeadshot,
  KikoJamesHeadshot,
  KirstieAndJeremyHeadshot,
  KirstieHeadshot,
  KJEstudilloHeadshot,
  LarkinPoyntonHeadshot,
  MitchVillarealHeadhsot,
  MoanaRakanaceHeadshot,
  NoelleFrancoHeadshot,
  PhuongLeHeadshot,
  SamMooreHeadshot,
  TonyRayHeadshot,
  TracySeilerHeadshot,
  TrishaOcampoHeadshot,
  YutaNakamuraHeadshot,
  defaultHeadshot,
]

export const buildArtistsData = (artists) => {
  return artists.map((artist, idx) => {
    return {
      ...artist,
      imageUrl:
        idx >= 43
          ? defaultHeadshot
          : images[`${artist.firstName}${artist.lastName}Headshot`],
    }
  })
}
```

And this is how it was used in my Artists component:

```
const ArtistsPage = () => {
 const artists = buildArtistsData(ARTISTS)

...

<div className={classes.flexContainer}>
          {artists
            .map(
              (
                { city, currentTeam, firstName, lastName, imageUrl },
                idx: number
              ) => {
                return (
                  <div className={classes.flexItem} key={idx}>
                    <img
                      className={classes.artistCardImg}
                      src={imageUrl}
                      alt='artist-image'
                    />
                    <div className={classes.artistCardName}>
                      {`${firstName} ${lastName}`.toUpperCase()}
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes.artistCardText}>{city}</div>
                    <div className={classes.artistCardText}>{currentTeam}</div>
                  </div>
                )
              }
            )}
        </div>
```

But now that I am using Gatsbyjs and data none of the above will work anymore. Here is what I am working with on the converted Gatsbyjs page:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

import { useStyles } from './styles'

const ArtistsPage = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data)
  const classes = useStyles()
  // const { images } = props

  return (
    <section>
      <article className={classes.artistsContainer}>
        <div className={classes.flexContainer}>
          {data.allArtistsJson.edges.map(({ node }, idx) => {
            return (
              <div className={classes.flexItem} key={idx}>
                <div>
                  {images.map((img, idx) => (
                    <Img
                      key={idx}
                      fluid={img.node.childImageSharp.fluid}
                    />
                  ))}
                </div>
                <div className={classes.artistCardName}>
                  {`${node.firstName} ${node.lastName}`.toUpperCase()}
                </div>
                <div className={classes.artistCardText}>{node.city}</div>
                <div className={classes.artistCardText}>{node.currentTeam}</div>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  )
}
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    headshots: allFile(filter: { absolutePath: { regex: "/headshots/" } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

ArtistsPage.propTypes = {
  firstName: PropTypes.string,
  lastName: PropTypes.string,
  currentTeam: PropTypes.string,
  headshots: PropTypes.string,
  dropdown: PropTypes.string,
  data: PropTypes.array,
  images: PropTypes.string,
}

export default ArtistsPage
```

I was trying to pull image data as props using
const { image } = props - but that throws an error so I am really confused as to what and how to map over this to pull my images in for the correct artist.

Also here is my config.js file for reference:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Platform Showcase',
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud',
    'gatsby-plugin-image',
    // {
    //   resolve: "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics",
    //   options: {
    //     trackingId: "",
    //   },
    // },
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        icon: 'src/images/icon.png',
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-mdx',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'images',
        path: './src/images/',
      },
      __key: 'images',
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `headshots`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/artists/headshots`,
      },
      __key: 'headshots',
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'pages',
        path: './src/pages/',
      },
      __key: 'pages',
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-google-fonts',
      options: {
        fonts: ['material icons', 'roboto:300,400,500,700'],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-theme-material-ui`,
    `gatsby-transformer-json`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `./src/data/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-root-import',
      options: {
        src: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        containers: path.join(__dirname, 'src/containers'),
        images: path.join(__dirname, 'src/images'),
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Any help anyone is willing to give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All images are located in the images/artists/headshots/ path.

Comment: "but that throws an error so I am really confused" Can you provide more details? Is the query working on `localhost:8000/___graphql`? What is `allArtistsJson`? I don't see any reference in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data, when using page queries, is always under `props.data` so your nesting should look like:

```
      {data.headshots.edges.map(({ node }, idx) => {
        return (
          <div className={classes.flexItem} key={idx}>
            <Img fluid={node.childImageSharp.fluid} />
          </div>
        )
      })}
```

*Note: I'm assuming that your GraphQL query retrieves properly the data. Test it at `localhost:8000/___graphql` and tweak your filesystem if needed*

Each image is each `node` itself (according to query structure) so, since your query is aliasing your `allFile` as `headshots`, your data is stored in `props.data.headshots`.

Comment: Thank you , I just saw that gatsby-image has been depreciated so I am going to have to refactor anyways. But thank you for the clarity.